# PDO database user exist control

Tags: php, mysql, pdo, php-7

```
if(isset($_GET['id'])){
    $nome = $_GET['nome'];
    $cognome = $_GET['cognome'];
    $id = $_GET['id'];
    $sql = "UPDATE utenti SET nome = :nome, cognome = :cognome WHERE id = :id";
    $req = $dbh->prepare($sql);
    $req->execute(
        array(
            ":nome" => $nome,
            ":cognome" => $cognome,
            ":id" => $id,
            )
        );
} else {
    $nome = $_GET['nome'];
    $cognome = $_GET['cognome'];
    $sql = "INSERT INTO utenti (nome, cognome) VALUES (:nome, :cognome)";
    $req = $dbh->prepare($sql);
    $req->execute(
        array(
            ":nome" => $nome,
            ":cognome" => $cognome,
            )
        );
}
```

Hello everyone. I have this code that inserts or updates a form's data within a database. I would like to include an "if" check that you are checking that the user does not already exist in the database. How can I do? Thank you

Comment: by writing a select statement to fetch any records with that username, and then checking how many rows are returned. If it's 0 rows, then the user doesn't already exist.

Comment: Hi ADyson, thanks for asked. Can you pass an example of instruction? Thank you

Comment: **note** it is possible for people to have to same first and last name. You should consider using an e-mailaddress or username to create uniqueness in your database

Comment: @DarkBee So you just ignore the ID?

Comment: @RonvanderHeijden If you want to update an existing record you use the id, but if you want to check if someone is already registered you can't rely on the name

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

```
               $nome = $_GET['nome'];
            //Searching the nome in the database
                    $req = $dbh->prepare("SELECT COUNT(*) AS anzahl FROM user WHERE Benutzername = :nome");
            //Counts the rows with the given nom
                    $req->bindParam(':nome', $nome, PDO::PARAM_STR);
                    $req->execute();
                    $result = $req->fetch();
                    if ($result[0] > 0) {
            //already exists - A row was found 
                        echo "Already exists";
                    }
                    else {
            //not existing - There was no row with that username
                     "Your Insertquery, use $req2 here"
                    }
```

Edit 2: This should work now ^^

Comment: Please consider using `prepared statements` in your answer

Comment: Neither of your codes would have actually worked. Do you have any real life experience with PDO?

Comment: Works fine for me ... So, im happy

Comment: Don't be so happy, it is giving you false positives. It will tell you that every user exists

Comment: YES! Works :) Thanks!